# Finding the limit of a polynomial

Tags: limits, polynomials

What's the limit of $a$ in

$$\lim_{(y^2 - x^3)^2\to\infty} {(y^2 - x^3)}^2 - |x| > a^2$$

Is there even enough information to solve this? It seems like x and y could tend to a variety of things.

Comment: ...  woops sorry!!

Comment: Sorry, z was a bad choice of a variable. It's a real number.

Answer (score 1):

Select $L\in \mathbb R$ arbitrarily.
For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $x_n=n+|L|$, $y_n=\sqrt{\sqrt{L+|L|+n}+(n+|L|)^3}$. (Note that all radicands are positive).
Then $y_n^2-x_n^3=\sqrt{L+|L|+n}\to\infty$, but $(y_n^2-x_n^3)^2-|x_n|=L$.
In other words, *nothing* can be said about $(y^2-x^3)^2-|x|$ if we only know that $y^2-x^3\to\infty$.

Comment: The limit is $$\lim_{(y^2 - x^3)^2\to\infty} {(y^2 - x^3)}^2 - |x| > a^2$$, not $$\lim_{y^2 - x^3\to\infty} {(y^2 - x^3)}^2 - |x| > a^2$$ Which is actually even less information.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{\left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2\to+\infty}\left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2 - \left|x\right| > a^2$$

---

Take $x\to+\infty$ (so $x>0$) and $y=\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x}}$.

$\left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2=\left(\left(\sqrt{x^3+\sqrt{x}}\right)^2 - x^3\right)^2=\left(x^3+\sqrt{x} - x^3\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2=x\to+\infty$

And $\left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2 - \left|x\right| = x - x = 0$

---

Take $x=0$ and $y\to+\infty$.

$\left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2=y^4\to+\infty$

$\left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2 - \left|x\right| = \left(y^2 - x^3\right)^2 \to+\infty$

---

So your limit doesn't even exist.

Comment: How did you get from $y^2-x^3\to\pm\infty$ to $y^2-x^3\pm\sqrt{|x|}\to\pm\infty$?

Comment: @user1825464 : Doesn't matter, it's false ^.^